# If $a\in\mathcal {A},$ and $\Vert a\Vert <1$, then $e-a$ is regular element of Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with unit $e$.

Tags: banach-algebras

I was reading an article yesterday which was silent on the algebra of Banach. In that article was provided this example

**If $a\in\mathcal {A},$ and $\Vert a\Vert <1$, then $e-a$ is regular element of Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with unit $e$.** Prove!!!

Please if someone can let them solve this example, to see how it looks choice, because it seems interesting example.

I hope that someone will help me, thank you preliminarily

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we show that $(I-A)$ is invertible?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110274/how-can-we-show-that-i-a-is-invertible)

Comment: @JonasMeyer:  This question is posed in the more general context of general Banach algebras, allowing the case $\dim \mathcal A = \infty$, so I would not class it as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110274/how-can-we-show-that-i-a-is-invertible, since that question explicitly refers to matrices of finite size.  Just my thoughts on the matter.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "regular" the OP means "invertable"; that is, that there exists $b \in \mathcal A$ with $b(e - a) = (e - a)b = e$. To see that such $b$ exists for $\Vert a \Vert < 1$, note that we have, for any positive integer $m$,

$(e - a) \sum_0^m a^j = e - a^{m + 1}, \tag{1}$

in which we understand that $a^0 = 1$.  If we now let $m \to \infty$, the sum on the left converges because it is majorized, term by term,  by the ordinary, real geometric sequence $\Vert a \Vert^j$:

$\Vert a^j \Vert \le \Vert a \Vert^j; \tag{2}$

thus, setting

$S_m = \sum_0^m a^j,  \tag{3}$

we have

$\Vert S_{m + k} - S_m \Vert = \Vert \sum_{m + 1}^{m + k} a^j \Vert$
$\le \Vert a^m\Vert \sum_1^k \Vert a \Vert^j \le \Vert a^m\Vert \sum_1^\infty \Vert a \Vert^j = \Vert a \Vert^m \dfrac{\Vert a \Vert}{1 - \Vert a \Vert}; \tag{4}$

since $\Vert a \Vert^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$, (4) shows that $S_m$ is Cauchy; hence $S_m \to S \in \mathcal A$ as $m \to \infty$ as well.  Turning now to (1), and again letting $m \to \infty$, we see that

$(e - a)S = e \tag{5}$

since $a^m \to 0$:  $\Vert a^m \Vert \le \Vert a \Vert^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$.  Furthermore, since we also have

$(\sum_0^m a^j) (e - a) = e - a^{m + 1} \tag{6}$

we in addition have

$(e - a)S = e; \tag{7}$

(5) and (7) show that

$S = \sum_0^\infty a^j \tag{8}$

is the inverse of $e - a$; thus $e - a$ is invertible or "regular" as was to be shown.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @user145717:  you're quite welcome!  Glad to help out!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Take $e+a+a^2+\cdots$ (why converges?). Then,
$$(e-a)(e+a+a^2+\cdots)=e+a-a+a^2-a^2+\cdots$$