# Inverse Function Theorem for Banach Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In the middle of a proof of the Inverse Function Theorem (namely, the proof of Baby Rudin), we use the fact that if $A$ is invertible and:

$$ ||B-A||~||A^{-1}|| <1$$

then $B$ is invertible. The proof for this, however, relies on the fact that the vector spaces are finite dimensional (because it concludes that $B$ is bijective by using that it is injective). How do we circumvent this, if we want to prove that IFT in banach spaces?

Comment: This is true in general for continuous operator between Banach spaces. You can find a proof in Murphy's *C$\hspace{0pt}^*$-algebras and Operator Theory*, Theorem 1.2.3.

Comment: For $\lVert X\rVert < 1$, the Neumann series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n$ is convergent, and gives you the inverse of $I - X$. Apply to $X = I - BA^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  $X$ is any Banach space, with $A, B \in L(X)$ bounded linear operators and $A$ invertible, we have, in the operator norm, using the hypothesis presented in the text of the question,

$\Vert I - A^{-1}B \Vert = \Vert A^{-1}(A - B)\Vert \le \Vert A^{-1} \Vert \Vert A - B \Vert < 1. \tag{1}$

Since (1) shows that

$\Vert I - A^{-1}B \Vert < 1, \tag{2}$

we have

$A^{-1}B = I - (I - A^{-1}B) \tag{3}$

is invertible; this follows from the well-known result that $\Vert C \Vert <1$, $C \in L(X)$, implies $I - C$ invertible; a detailed proof may be found in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909836/if-a-in-mathcal-a-and-vert-a-vert-1-then-e-a-is-regular-element-of-b).  Writing

$A^{-1}B = K, \tag{4}$

with $K$ invertible, also allows us to write

$B = AK; \tag{5}$

$B$, being the product of invertible operators, is itself invertible; indeed, we have

$B^{-1} = K^{-1}A^{-1}. \tag{6}$